# Find Max & Min values

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the minimum and maximum value. I am running into following two issues:

1. When entering only negative numbers, the max value will be equal to 0, not the input's maximum value.
2. I have a similar issue when entering only positive numbers. Basically the smallest value will be 0 not the input's value.

Any tips would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    while (input != -1)
    {
        cin >> input;
        if(input != -1)
        {
            if(input > max)
            {
                max = input;
            }

            if(input < min)
            {
                min = input;
            }
        }
    }
    cout <<"Max: " << max << " Min " << min << endl;
}
```

Comment: The problem is with your initial values for `max` and `min`.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Think about it... you want `max` to start out as low as possible (so that any input value greater than it will become the new maximum).  And, conversely, you want `min` to start out as high as possible.  You can find constants to help you with this here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Comment: Give an initial value to `input`, such as `int input = 0`.

Answer (score 3):

From your code I guessed that there will be no negative number. Then do something like this:

**EDIT**:This part from another answer will be good.

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int input;
    int hasInput = 0;
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); //#include <limits>

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        if(input == -1) break;
        hasInput = 1;
        if(input > max)
        {
            max = input;
        }
        if(input < min)
        {
            min = input;
        }
     }
        if(hasInput == 1)
        cout <<"Max: " << max << " Min " << min << endl;
 }
```

Comment: As is, your code will print out these min/max values even if -1 is typed first - particularly confusing/misleading as min > max.  Good to see `while (cin >> input)`... +1 for that alone.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, instead of setting to 0, ask for the first number before the while loop and set min and max to that number. As a side note, using -1 as a quit condition for something which accepts numerical input might lead to problems, you might want to ask them for the number of numbers beforehand or detect non numerical input to end the program.

EDIT: example code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int input;
bool hasInput = false;
cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> input;
int max = input;
int min = input; 

cout << "Enter number: ";
while (cin >> input)
{
    if(input == -1) break;
    hasInput = true;
    if(input > max)
    {
        max = input;
    }
    if(input < min)
    {
        min = input;
    }
    cout << "Enter number: ";
 }
    if(hasInput)
    cout <<"Max: " << max << " Min " << min << endl;
}
```

Forgot to check if the first input is -1... im sure you can figure that one out.

Comment: Thanks @user3482801, but I am still having issues. Could you give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Turix said, the problem is because of your initial `max` and `min` values. Your `max` value should be the smallest possible integer value so that *anything* is greater than it, similarly your `min` should be the largest possible integer value. With this in hand, intialize your variables like this:

```
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); //#include <limits>
```

Comment: That change alone will print out these min/max values even if -1 is typed first - particularly confusing/misleading as min > max.